# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/DefaultHostnameVerifier;

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, office365, apache-httpclient-4.x, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to use `Exchange Web Services` `Java API` in a `Office365` `Android` app I'm making, but keep getting this error.

Relevant stack information below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/DefaultHostnameVerifier;
        at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.EwsSSLProtocolSocketFactory.<clinit>(EwsSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:86)
        at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeServiceBase.createConnectionSocketFactoryRegistry(ExchangeServiceBase.java:212)
        at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeServiceBase.initializeHttpClient(ExchangeServiceBase.java:194)
        at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeServiceBase.<init>(ExchangeServiceBase.java:170)
        at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.<init>(ExchangeService.java:3779)
        at com.microsoft.office365.connect.SendMailActivity.onBookMeetingButton1(SendMailActivity.java:140)
```

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.microsoft.office365.connect-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.EwsSSLProtocolSocketFactory.<clinit>(EwsSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:86)
        at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeServiceBase.createConnectionSocketFactoryRegistry(ExchangeServiceBase.java:212)
        at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeServiceBase.initializeHttpClient(ExchangeServiceBase.java:194)
        at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeServiceBase.<init>(ExchangeServiceBase.java:170)
        at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.<init>(ExchangeService.java:3779)
        at com.microsoft.office365.connect.SendMailActivity.onBookMeetingButton1(SendMailActivity.java:140)
```

...

```
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 20 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I have the httpclient 4.3.jar in my /libs/ folder and these are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

// base OData library:
compile group: 'com.microsoft.services', name: 'odata-engine-core', version: '0.12.1'
compile group: 'com.microsoft.services', name: 'odata-engine-android-impl', version: '0.12.1', ext:'aar'

// choose the discovery and outlook services
compile group: 'com.microsoft.services', name: 'discovery-services', version: '0.12.1'
compile group: 'com.microsoft.services', name: 'outlook-services', version: '0.12.1'

// Azure Active Directory Library
compile group: 'com.microsoft.aad', name: 'adal', version: '1.1.1'

//compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4'
//compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.3'
//compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
//compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
}
```

Is anyone able to spot the issue or how I could possibly fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Its me again. Found a solution for this?

Comment: @Tinashe, nope ditched it! Went with office 365 sdk for Android instead.

Comment: With the office 365 sdk have you tried accessing shared resources? Like shared Calendars.

Comment: @Tinashe I'm actually trying to work that out at the moment. Been in contact with the developers of the sdk. Can update with information when I get home in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried by adding following dependency. Now it's working fine for me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Awesome answer! I am not using android, but it fixed this exact error for me!

Comment: @KrunalShah you should put this in pom.xml in your maven project

Comment: how to add this lines @Rams

Comment: @RevathiManoharan you need to add the above-mentioned dependency in Pom.xml in your Java project

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.I fixed it by upgrading all the `org.apache.httpcomponents` libraries under `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue but fixed adding httpclient-osgi in pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient-osgi</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

It works fine..